# Not able to publish a service fabric application on azure service fabric cluster

Tags: api, .net-core, runtime-error, azure-service-fabric

I have developed a **Service Fabric Application** project in **dot net** .
I have created a **secured service fabric cluster on Azure**. I have imported the cluster certificate in my cerficated manager on my machine under **Current User : Personal & Trusted root Certificates.** When I am trying to **publish** a service fabric application. It's giving error like:

```
8>WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
8>Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest : Operation canceled.
8>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
8>Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:159 char:28
8>+     $clusterManifestText = Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest
8>+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
8>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Get-ServiceFabr 
8>   icClusterManifest], FabricTransientException
8>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetClusterManifestErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.GetClusterManifest
```

Application is working fine on local cluster but not on azure. Is there any configuration setting missing?

Comment: Can you share the commands you are using to publish the application?

Comment: I am publishing the application through visual studio.

Comment: Can you confirm if your scripts are using the right parameters? make sure that Certificate Storage is being passed is My and not Machine, the Certificate Thumbprint is correct(if you copied it from certificate store, ensure not dodgy chars has been copied over), and the cluster url you are trying to connect is correct.

Comment: yes I checked  thumbprint, url, and storage is also 'My'. What may be the other configuration

Comment: Can you try connecting to the cluster using the example provided here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ncdevguy/2016/12/25/connecting-to-a-remote-azure-service-fabric-cluster-using-powershell/